# Proving composite functions

Tags: functions

I've just started learning functions but my algebra is letting me down:

If $f(x)$ = $\frac{1}{x+1}$, prove that $f^2(x)$ = $\frac{x+1}{x+2}$. Hence prove $f^3(x) ...$

Am I right in thinking that $f^2(x)$ = $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1}$?

After working through, I end up with $\frac{x+1}{1}$

Comment: Yes you are, but you didn't finish well.

Comment: multiply numerator and denominator both with $x+1$.

Comment: One good and simple way to check your algebra is to just plug in values.  $f(0)=1\implies f^2(0)=f(1)=\frac 12$ which is not consistent with your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac1{x+1},$$
$$f^2(x)=\frac1{\frac1{x+1}+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+2},$$
$$f^3(x)=\frac1{\frac{x+1}{x+2}+1}=\frac{x+2}{2x+3},$$
$$f^4(x)=\frac1{\frac{x+2}{2x+3}+1}=\frac{2x+3}{3x+5},$$

$$f^n(x)=\frac{F_{n-1}x+F_n}{F_nx+F_{n+1}},$$

where $F_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Proof by induction: for $n=1$, $$f(x)=\frac1{x+1}=\frac{F_0x+F_1}{F_1x+F_2},$$

If the formula is true for $n=k$, then
$$f^k(x)=\frac{F_{k-1}x+F_k}{F_kx+F_{k+1}},$$

and
$$f^{k+1}(x)=\frac1{f^k(x)+1}=\frac1{\frac{F_{k-1}x+F_k}{F_kx+F_{k+1}}+1}=\frac{F_kx+F_{k+1}}{F_{k-1}x+F_k+F_kx+F_{k+1}}=\frac{F_kx+F_{k+1}}{F_{k+1}x+F_{k+2}}.$$

QED.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, here is $f^2(x)$ as a hint$$f^2(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1} = \frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x+1}} = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617436/a-problem-related-to-the-composition-f-2-circ-g2/2617447#2617447), following that method gives us: $$f^3(x)=f(f(f(x))) = f(\frac{x+1}{x+2}) = \frac{x+2}{2x+3}$$

So, yes, you have correctly computed $f^2(x)$ but not $f^3(x)$.

Comment: You have not accepted any of your questions thus far. Accepting questions is an easy process, just choose the tick mark for the answer which you feel helped you the most. You can also upvote the answers you receive.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1} = \frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x+1}} = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$
so your approach is right but you made a small mistake while manipulating the expression I believe.

Answer (score 0):

$$f^2= \frac 1 {f+1},\text{and } f^3 =\frac 1 {f^2+1}$$
 $$f^2= \frac 1 {f+1}= \frac 1 {\frac 1 {x+1}+1}=\frac {x+1}{x+2}$$
 $$f^3= \frac 1 {f^2+1}= \frac 1 { {\frac {x+1}{x+2}}+1}=\frac {x+2}{2x+3}$$